# Rotating object whilst moving across screen Unity2d

Tags: c#, android, unity3d-2dtools

This is the code I am using to move an object across the screen:

```
public float speed = 5f;

void Update () {

        transform.Translate (new Vector3(1,0,0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

What I want is for the object to rotate on its axis as its moving across the screen. I've tried animation, but the animation seemed to make it rotate but not move across the screen. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public float speed = 5f;

void Update () {

    transform.Translate (new Vector3(1,0,0) * speed * Time.deltaTime)
    transform.rotate = new Vector3(0,0,speed);
}
```

That should work